# How to use ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 in bash script for qsub

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, qsub

I have tensorflow 1.4.1 installed by `pip`, but the system-default gcc libs are not latest, that running

> `import tensorflow`

will cause this error

> `ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.16' not found`

Since I don't have root permission, I built the gcc libs, and use

> `alias python_cpu='/path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /path/other_libs /path/python'`

to run tensorflow on CPU.

Now I've generated thousands of **bash scripts** and want to run them with **qsub**

within each script `oo.sh` writes

> `#!/usr/bin/bash`
>
> `python_cpu python_script.py different_params`

I've tried the below ideas but all **failed**.

1. Use `qsub -V oo.sh` to pass the `alias` into `oo.sh`.
2. Use `alias python_cpu=""` within the bash script.
3. Without `alias`, use `'/path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /path/other_libs /path/python' python_script.py params`.

By the way the `alias` of TF works well with the bash shell command line. Any suggestions of what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Get the scripts to work by

`#!/usr/bin/bash`

`python_cpu='/path/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /path/other_libs /path/python'`

`$python_cpu python_script.py different_params`

instead of using `alias`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a cluster, you should try using a module file.  Ideally, the sysadmin who setup the cluster to use python would provide an appropriately configured module for python and tensorflow.  If not you could make a simple request to add or point to the appropriate `libc.so` file.  Then you load the module file in your `oo.sh` using the command

`module load foo-module`

Alternatively, you can write your own module file to setup the environment you need.

[Basic tutorial here](https://www.hpc.cam.ac.uk/using-clusters/user-environment-and-modules)